# convert mysql query to laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I would like to convert this query to Laravel query builder syntax. Any help. Thanks.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.price
FROM cars c  , garage g
WHERE (g.name = 'main') AND (g.id= c.garage)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Give us some examples of things you've tried and how is this supposed to work too... because even the query looks a little  shady from my point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\DB::table('cars')
   ->join('garage', 'garage.id', '=', 'cars.garage')       
   ->where('garage.name', 'main')
```

The above solves the garage and cars part, but you never specified what is aliased to p. If p is a different table then you need to add another call to `join()` and making the following

```
 \DB::table('cars')
   ->join('garage', 'garage.id', '=', 'cars.garage')
   //<Other table join goes here for table aliased to p>
   ->where('garage.name', 'main')
   ->select(['p.id', 'p.name', 'p.price'])
   ->get();
```